# Highstock timezone trouble

Tags: highcharts

I have GWT application which uses Highstock JS library. 
I'd like to implement following use case:

User select start and end dates and time from DateField and TimeField controls (GXT). These controls operate with java.util.Date values. I initialize end date by new Date() and start date by current date minus last hour. Controls display dates in user browser's timezone (e.g. GMT+4).
There is a control to select timezone to build chart: local or user defined.

I need to build Highstock chart in selected timezone. Data is stored in database in UTC.

Which settings, time adjustments I need to implement in order to display correct chart?

Answer (score 0):

In general it is correct to use UTC for all timestamps and perform local changes according to user timezone or similar locally in your browser. If you set [global.useUTC](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#global.useUTC) while creating your Highstock chart, all dates will be handled in UTC timezone.